# HLS support on ICS

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, stagefright

We are having certain hardware installed with ICS operating system where we need to play secure m3u8 (using key files just like how IOS handles).

We need to control playback in many ways  like fast forward,rewind,manipulating stream on the fly and show Ad's in between etc.

We think that this all can be solved if we are able to play .ts files using android player, this way we can access many m3u8 one time and write our own (which can act as proxy) and serve the ts streams to player.Here we can even manipulate many m3u8 ts streams and combine on the fly.

Need to understand is it possible or not? How Stagefright framework is handling internally? Anybody has knowledge of Stagefright framework?

We just want it to play on our hardware, we dont need other OS support.Let me know any pointers for same.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend ignoring the HLS support in the Android classes and try an approach that uses the underlying video frameworks in C.

Have a look at how the XBMC project is loading the video decoder libraries: https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/master/xbmc/cores/ The amlplayer and omxplayer contain implementations for different chipsets. I don't know what chipset you're using, but it might be one of those. There are also xbmc branches with tegra support.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.The chip we are using is Amlogic
http://openlinux.amlogic.com/wiki/index.php/Arm

It is called M1/M3 chip. You can search google to
get more info:
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/32431-a-little-help-amlogic-processors-can-someone-fill-me-in/

We need support only for ics.